# Problem understanding treesort in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, tree

I am trying to figure out how exactly does treesort from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort) work (I understand flatten, insert and foldr).

I suppose what's being done in treesort is applying insert for each element on the **list** thus generating a tree and then flattening it. The only problem I can't overcome here is where the **list** (that is the argument of the function) is hiding (because it is not written anywhere as an argument except for the function type declaration).

One more thing: since dot operator is function composition, why is it an error when I change: `treesort = flatten . foldr insert Leaf` to `treesort = flatten( foldr insert Leaf )`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what's being done in treesort is applying insert for each element on the list thus generating a tree and then flattening it.

Exactly right.

> [Where is the list hiding?]

In a functional language, you don't have to give the arguments of a value of function type.  For example if I write

```
f = concat . map (map toUpper)
```

I get a function of type `[[Char]] -> [Char]`.  This
function expects an argument even though there's no argument in the defining equation.
It's *exactly* the same as if I had written

```
f strings = (concat . map (map toUpper)) strings
```

> Since the dot operator is function composition, why is it wrong to change `f . g` to `f (g)`?

They don't mean the same thing.   What happens when each is applied to `x`?

```
(f . g) x  = f (g x)

(f (g)) x  = (f g) x
```

You can see the applications associate differently, and `f. g` is different from `f g`.

It's a type error because `foldr insert Leaf` is a function from lists to trees, and `flatten` is meant to be applied to a single tree, not to a function.

Comment: I'm not sure that `f strings = ...` and `f = \strings -> ...` is the _same_ things.

Comment: @ony: It is the same in just the way that `["a", "b"]` is the same as `"a":"b":[]`; they are two different ways of writing the same value.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your last question first, you're getting an error because `.` is a function composition operator that takes two functions (in this case `flatten` and `foldr insert Leaf`). If you want to rewrite the code without the use of `.`, you'll need to create a function that takes some parameter:

```
-- // Pass the 'list' to the first function and the 
-- // result of the call to the second function
treesort list = flatten (foldr insert Leaf list)
```

This also explains where the `list` parameter was hiding. When composing functions, you don't need to write parameters explicitly, because the result of the expression `f . g` is a function that takes some parameter, calls `g` and then calls `f`:

```
-- // function composition..
composed = f . g
-- // ..is equivalent to declaring a function:
composed x = f (g x)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the treesort function at the link takes a list argument, not a tree, so "tree" probably isn't the best choice of variable name.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, I realized that too - thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, as long as you are not familiar with the pointless style, it is useful to do epsilon-conversion mentally.

If f is an expression with function type, then one can convert it to
    \e -> (f) e

And, if we have a definition like

```
a = \e -> (f) e
```

we can always safely rewrite it as

```
a e = (f) e
```

Thus

```
treesort = flatten . foldr insert Leaf
```

is the same as

```
treesort list = (flatten . foldr insert Leaf) list
```